# KeywordAnalyzer to handle different spellings of words with umlauts

Tags: java, solr, lucene

How can I make `KeywordAnalyzer` recognize names like *Müller* regardless of the spelling?

`KeywordAnalyzer` expects an exact match and I would like it to match *Müller* but also *Mueller* (*ue* digram) and *Muller*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following custom analyzer does the trick:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.KeywordTokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.de.GermanNormalizationFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.ASCIIFoldingFilter;

public final class KeywordAnalyzerDE extends Analyzer {
    public KeywordAnalyzerDE() {
    }

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName) {
        final Tokenizer source = new KeywordTokenizer();

        TokenStream result;
        result = new GermanNormalizationFilter(source);
        result = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(result);

        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, result);
    }
}
```

The key is `GermanNormalizationFilter`:

> It allows for the fact that ä, ö and ü are sometimes written as ae, oe and ue.
>
> - 'ß' is replaced by 'ss'
> - 'ä', 'ö', 'ü' are replaced by 'a', 'o', 'u', respectively.
> - 'ae' and 'oe' are replaced by 'a', and 'o', respectively.
> - 'ue' is replaced by 'u', when not following a vowel or q.

I added `ASCIIFoldingFilter` just in case there are other diacritic characters in processed text.

Reviewing the source code was really helpful:

- [Original `KeywordAnalyzer`](https://github.com/cloudera/lucene-solr/blob/25d722e35238cca776abbe3a621e0c5b733e762d/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/KeywordAnalyzer.java)
- [Different filters for German](https://github.com/cloudera/lucene-solr/tree/25d722e35238cca776abbe3a621e0c5b733e762d/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/de)